# Makefile compiles every source every time

Tags: makefile

I'm a beginner (in everything, really) studying C. For the exercises of a book, I have made this project directory:

```
book_name
├── chapter01
│   ├── exer01
│   │   └── exe.c
│   └── exer02
│       └── exe.c
├── chapter02
│   ├── exer01
│   │   └── exe.c
│   └── exer02
│       ├── exe.c
│       └── exe_better.c
├── Makefile
├── notes.txt
├── README.md
├── .git
│   └── git_stuff
└── .gitignore
```

With more chapters and exercises. Each exercise is a program and is in its own folder, because sometimes I come back and make exe_better.c after learning something new, leaving both versions. It was getting repetitive typing the compile command for each exercise, and while searching for an automated way to do it, I found make. After digging, I got a Makefile that does what I wanted initially, i.e., compiles for me with a single command. My Makefile:

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c17 -pedantic-errors

SOURCES := $(shell find . -name '*.c')
TARGETS := $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SOURCES))
OUT := $(shell find . -name '*.out')

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGETS) 

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@.out

clean:
        rm $(OUT)
```

It puts an .out extension so git ignores the binaries. My problem is that "make" compiles each file every time, even if a .c source has not been changed. Make is supposed to only compile a file if it has changed (right?), so I am obviously doing something wrong. All related questions that I found involved .o, .d, or .h files and linking, but I don't need those (yet) and couldn't adapt the answers to my problem.

**Edit**

With help from the comments, I was able to find a solution. Edited Makefile:

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c17 -pedantic-errors

SOURCES := $(shell find . -name '*.c')
TARGETS := $(patsubst %.c,%.out,$(SOURCES))
OUT := $(shell find . -name '*.out')

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGETS) 

%.out: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm $(OUT)
```

Comment: Try `%.out: %.c:`. `make` doesn't have a target to compare the .c timestamp to.

Comment: Using `%.out: %.c` instead of `%: %.c` keeps track of changes, but loses the `.out` extension.

Comment: Did you change `-o $@.out` to something else?

Comment: I did not. Only `%: %.c` to `%.out: %.c`.

Comment: And you are getting what extension? I think I would expect `.out.out` actually, so maybe you should change to `-o $@`.

Comment: Getting no extensions with the previous attempt, e.g., `hello.c` makes a `hello` binary. Trying only `-o $@` gives the same result.

Comment: So to be clear you now have `%:.out %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@.out`? and you get no `.out` extension whatsoever?

Comment: Yes. `%.out: %.c      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@.out` and I get no extension whatsoever.

Comment: Your dependencies need to match up. Either force the `TARGETS` variable to also have an `.out` extension, or get rid of the extension throughout. The way `make` tracks what has been made is by looking for whether the target file exists and has a date newer than the source file; but if you are looking for the wrong source file (or vice versa) `make` concludes that because the file you told it to look for doesn't exist, it needs to be made.

Comment: @tripleee It doesn't really, as that one uses explicit targets, which you try to avoid in good `makefiles`, as the OP is.

Comment: This is a fairly common beginner FAQ so there are probably better duplicates. If you find a good one, please vote to close.

Comment: @tripleee although the related question helped me understand `make` better, it didn't solve my problem at first, because I don't know how to replicate it in general, that is, without typing a rule for each file. But, your first suggestion to put an `.out` extension directly to the variable `TARGETS`, combined with the help of @user207421, solved my problem! I used the `addsuffix` function to do that and the rule `%:.out: %.c`. Thank you both so much.

Comment: Simply `$(patsubst %.c,%.out,$(SOURCES))` should be sufficient.

Comment: That's way better than what I did. Thanks.